# Missing delimiter error involving split and array environments

Tags: environments, arrays, delimiters, split

The following code works fine

```
     \documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
        \usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
        \usepackage[english]{babel}
        \usepackage{amsmath}
        \usepackage{amsthm}
    

    \begin{document}
            \begin{equation*}
            \begin{split}
                & x[0]\sim\mathcal{N}(\theta,1) \\ 
                & x[1]\sim\left\{\begin{array}{rcl}
                        \mathcal{N}(\theta,1) & \mbox{if} & \theta\geq0 \\ 
                        \mathcal{N}(\theta,2) & \mbox{if} & \theta<0 \\
            \end{array}\right.
            \end{split}
            \end{equation*}
            \end{document}
```

..while the following is giving me "Missing delimiter" error

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\begin{document}
    \begin{equation*}
    \begin{split}
    & var(\hat\theta_1) = \frac{1}{4}(var(x[0])+var(x[1])) \\
    & var(\hat\theta_2) = \frac{4}{9}var(x[0])+\frac{1}{9}var(x[1]) \\
    & var(\hat\theta_1) = \left\{\begin{array}{rcl}
            \frac{18}{36}(\theta,1) & \mbox{if} & \theta\geq0 \\ 
            \frac{27}{36}(\theta,1) & \mbox{if} & \theta<0 \\
    \end{array}\right \\
    & var(\hat\theta_2) = \left\{\begin{array}{rcl}
            \frac{20}{36}(\theta,1) & \mbox{if} & \theta\geq0 \\ 
            \frac{24}{36}(\theta,1) & \mbox{if} & \theta<0 \\
    \end{array}\right.
    \end{split}
    \end{equation*}
    \end{document}
```

The message is this

```
! Missing delimiter (. inserted):
<to be read again>
        \let
I.94 \end{split}

?
```

So, what am I missing?

Comment: unrelated but do you really use latin1 encoding? (the code once posted to this site is always utf-8 never latin1)

Comment: you have a missing delimiter or `.`here `\end{array}\right \\ ` (line 14)

Comment: What delimiter do I have to put?

Comment: You need to replace `\end{array}\right` with `\end{array}\right.` -- can you spot the difference?

Comment: Many Thanks. Would you be so kind to link me to a source explaining what that dot does? It didn't occur to me that the dot was actually part of the code

Comment: The "dot" is a place-holder for "nothing". When you use `\left` and `\right`, one generally uses delimiters at both ends. If, as in your case, there is no delimiter at the right, you still need to inform TeX about this fact -- by using ".".

Comment: you correctly used `\right.` a few lines down so I assumed you knew what this did sorry otherwise I would have said more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would like to suggest that you use the `cases` environment, provided by the `amsmath` environment, instead of an `array` environment embedded inside a `\left\{`/`\right.` pair. And, assuming that "var" is short for "variance", I think you should use upright lettering to denote that it's an operator rather than the product of variables named `v`, `a`, and `r`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % surely not 'latin1' ??
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'split' and 'cases' environments
\DeclareMathOperator{\Var}{Var} % variance "operator"

\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
    \Var(\hat\theta_1) &= \tfrac{1}{4}\bigl(\Var(x[0])+\Var(x[1])\bigr) \\
    \Var(\hat\theta_2) &= \tfrac{4}{9}\Var(x[0])+\tfrac{1}{9}\Var(x[1]) \\
    \Var(\hat\theta_1) &= 
        \begin{cases}
            \frac{18}{36}(\theta,1) & \text{if $\theta\geq0$} \\[\jot]
            \frac{27}{36}(\theta,1) & \text{if $\theta<0$} 
        \end{cases} \\
    \Var(\hat\theta_2) &= 
         \begin{cases}
            \frac{20}{36}(\theta,1) & \text{if $\theta\geq0$} \\[\jot]
            \frac{24}{36}(\theta,1) & \text{if $\theta<0$}
         \end{cases}
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hiiii do you have news? :-)

Comment: There is also actually the reply :-)